# ThreadPoolExecutor asyncio analogue?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I used to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` in my projects, running my synchronous functions in separate threads with it.

Nowadays I mostly use asynchronous code with `asyncio`, but I have a problem that I can't find a solution for using `asyncio`.

Let's say I have an async function

```
async def do_job(a, b, c, d):
     if a < b:
         raise CustomException("A is smaller than b")
     else:
         return True, "Work done"
```

> (just an example, in fact the function is very extensive, and raising custom exceptions in some cases is a mandatory part of it)

Assume that I need to run **100 instances** of a given function **with a limit of N** instances running simultaneously.
I also want to **receive results from the threads** as they execute **without waiting for all tasks to finish** (along **with the parameters** with which the given task was run) and also **handle errors** and **add new instances to the task pool** in some cases.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` allowed me to achieve this goal (not sure about adding new tasks to the pool because I didn't need it then), but I can't find anything in `asyncio` that meets my needs.

My example using ThreadPoolExecutor

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_threads) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(exec_f, a, b): a for a in param_list}

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        param_a = futures[future]
        try:
            result = future.result()
            # Process result
        except Exception as ex:
            # Process exception
```

Tell me, please, maybe I'm missing something, and this can be implemented with `asyncio`, or I should give up this idea and combine `asyncio` with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (it seems that this is not very correct).

Comment: You got any problems with `asyncio.wait`? Depending on how you need to control the numer of simultaneous running tasks, you can add new tasks to "pending" after a timeout, or use a semaphore in a decorator to your tasks (this can keep the pipe always full)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at asyncio.Future.add_done_callback.  That allows you to attach a sync function to any Task, to be run when the Task finishes.  (Task is a subclass of Future in asyncio.)

Answer (score 0):

You can control `max_threads` in asyncio using `Semaphore`. And add new tasks just using `create_task()`.

For example:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Semaphore


async def do_job(a, b):
    if a < b:
        raise Exception("A is smaller than b")
    else:
        return True, "Work done"


async def task_wrapper(semaphore: Semaphore, *args):
    await semaphore.acquire()
    try:
        result = await do_job(*args)
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
    finally:
        semaphore.release()


async def main():
    semaphore = Semaphore(max_threads)
    tasks = []
    for a in param_list:
        task = asyncio.create_task(task_wrapper(semaphore, a))
        tasks.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```